# Cassandra not using native methods

Tags: java, cassandra, jna, opensuse

I want cassandra to make use of native methods.

I installed jna as follows:

```
#install JNA 
zypper install --no-confirm jna

#create a link to it for cassandra
ln -s /usr/share/java/jna.jar $PATH_TO_CASSANDRA/apache-cassandra-1.0.7/lib/
```

but when I run

```
$PATH_TO_CASSANDRA/apache-cassandra-1.0.7/bin/cassandra -f
```

I get following message:

> INFO 10:36:05,594 Unable to link C library. Native methods will be
>   disabled.

I have researched a bit, and found that it gives out that message because it gets a `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when it calls `Native.register("c");` (found [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/tags/cassandra-0.6.10/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/CLibrary.java)). Its supposed to have something to do with jna.

How can I solve it? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `jna.library.path` set prior to invoking Cassandra? libc properly installed on the system?

Comment: How do I set jna.library.path on linux? or how do i check if it is set? glibc is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that zypper only has version 3.1 of jna, while Cassandra wants 3.2.7.

I grabbed a copy [here](https://github.com/twall/jna), and now it works like a charm.